# wxPython adding Flag

Tags: python, wxpython

I was playing with wx.Frame.SetWindowStyleFlag() and noticed that to add a new flag I can use either '+' or '|', both resulting the same. My question is, is there a situation where this yields a different result? And is there any performance difference between the 2? I noticed that book like wxPython Application development cookbook use '|' instead of '+'.

Comment: `|` is a bitwise OR, so the result **shouldn't** be the same for both `|` and `+` but I can't find enough information to give you a complete answer. For the time being you should probably stick to `|` since it is what all the documentation says you should use. Note that `00|11 == 00+11 == 11` but that `01|01 == 01` while `01+01 == 10`. Maybe you're getting lucky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend always using "|". The only time I've seen other bitwise operators used is in the AGW library's demos in the wxPython demo. I doubt there's a difference in speed though. The "|" is the only one I see used regularly and since Robin Dunn (creator of wxPython) is always using it, I think we should too.

Comment: I see. It's just that when I use "-" to remove a flag, it worked. I think it's a lot less confusing to use "+" and "-" to add and remove flag instead of "|" and "^". But if the creator himself use "|" and "^"... guess I gotta follow then. Hahaha.

Comment: I agree, but "+" and "-" are not bitwise operators, so they won't work in this case. I suspect this has more to do with wxPython's C++ / SWIG heritage than anything though.